# How to download Sankey plot in Shiny

Tags: r, image, download, shiny

I have a problem when downloading the plotted sankey diagram out of my shiny app code. I actually based my typing on the R documentation nevertheless nothing works fine here!
Here's the code

```
ui <- fluidPage( downloadButton('d', 'Download graph') )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$d <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
         'SankeyPlot.png'
       },
       content = function(file) {
         png(filename = "SankeyPlot.png",width = 550,height = 480,units = px,type = 'png')
         print(sankeyNetworkOutput("splot"))
         dev.off()
       },
      contentType = 'image/png'
     )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is this problem specific to sankey or happens also with base plots? It seems that given code contains unrelated information, can you edit your question to remove all un-necessary code?

Comment: The logo problem is common, the downlaod plot png isn't working only for sankey ! I don't know why!

Comment: `sankeyNetworkOutput` if from a package other than shiny, right? Please include `library(thispackage)` in your code, and everything else to make your code reproducible.

Comment: I would recommend splitting this question into two - now it's two unrelated problems (which makes this post too broad)

Comment: In fact I've added the library library(networkD3) while the probelm still exist!

Comment: Here you are, I modified the question to only one probelm <3

Comment: `D3`, which underlies the output of `networkD3`, generates an SVG, not an image like JPG or PNG, so you would have to include something that will convert the SVG to an image.

Answer (score 0):

SankeyNetworkD3 returns a 'networkD3' widget and not a png. I think you should use an html widget loader or a similar function like SaveNetwork.

Comment: Can you explain in a minimal example? I think your answer is the most correct! thats what I thought already however SaveNetwork produced errors!

Comment: I've tried this:

output$d <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "SankeyPlot"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      saveNetwork("spolts","C:/Users/Ali-Frady/Desktop/STAGE 2/DE",selfcontained = TRUE)
      dev.off()
    }
  )

Comment: Can you mention the errors that were produced? I am away from a workstation so can't reproduce.

Comment: It simply won't download and the browser  says : there is a problem in the server!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
library(networkD3)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton('d', 'Download graph'),  
  simpleNetworkOutput("network")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  network <- reactive({
    src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
             "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
    target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J",
                "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
    networkData <- data.frame(src, target)
    simpleNetwork(networkData)
  })

  output$network <- renderSimpleNetwork({
    network()
  })

  output$d <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      'SankeyPlot.html'
    },
    content = function(file) {
      saveNetwork(network(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Well this is the closest answer but still isn't working cause it doesn't give you the plotted graph, it actually gives you the web page components that I used in my shiny app!

Comment: @AliFrady Sorry I don't understand what you want. Could you rephrase ? What your app is supposed to do ?

Comment: what I want is whenever I click download I get the diagram already plotted as image or pdf or any other file. it means I want to print and  save the diagram plotted already !

Comment: I don't understand why  you don't display the graph in the app, and then click download to download it. Is it what you want?

Comment: Yes definitely, but the code you wrote didn't work that way! it just downloads a web page 'html' that contains all my app components but the graph!!

Comment: @AliFrady Obviously, there's only a download handler. I thought this was your question. I've just edited my answer. Is it ok now ? Now the app displays the network, and you can download it.

Comment: Well it gives the same result as the previous one !

Comment: @AliFrady No, the previous one did not display the network. You should seriously rephrase what you want. Please make an effort to be clear.

Comment: I made an answer to which I attached the image that captures the  returned result

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsLt2.png)

This is what I get if I include your code @Stéphane Laurent